# ViewModel in asp .net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a class VIEWMODEL

```
 public class EditViewModel 
    {
       
       
        public List<PersonnelModel> personnels { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentModel> documents { get; set; }
    }
```

and i want to edit the personnelModel ,this is a form filled with personal data x for example

but it doesn't work some one help me please

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.personnels)
    {
    <div class="col-md-4">
      
        <form asp-action="EditPers" method="post"  asp-route-id="@item.id">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.id" >
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.Nom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Nom">
               

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Prenom)">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Prenom" class="text-danger"></span>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Email">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Telephone">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Statut">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Statut" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-info text-white " />
                
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>}
```

i don't know how to write the edit code someone help me please

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? what is your wish ?

Comment: Do you want to write a controller to get the data ?

Comment: I want to edit just the personnelModel ,i try to do this,but it's not working

Comment: public ActionResult EditPers(int id,PersonnelModel item)
        {
            
                _context.Update(item);

                _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
          
                
              
            
       
            
          
        }

Comment: for binding list model you should  set index like: <input type="hidden" name="personnels[0].id" >

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you cannot pass data to controller,because the model binding failed.It's because your asp-for="item.xxx",so your passed data will be like this.
[image]

If you want to bind the data,Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditPersonnelModel()
        {
            EditViewModel e = new EditViewModel();
            List<PersonnelModel> list = new List<PersonnelModel> { new PersonnelModel { id = 1, Email = "123@123", Nom = "n1", Prenom = "p1", Statut = "s1", Telephone = "123" }, new PersonnelModel { id = 2, Email = "1234@1234", Nom = "n2", Prenom = "p2", Statut = "s2", Telephone = "1234" } };
            e.personnels = list;
            return View(e);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("id")]
        public ActionResult EditPers(PersonnelModel p)
        {
            EditViewModel e = new EditViewModel();
            List<PersonnelModel> list = new List<PersonnelModel> { new PersonnelModel { id = 1, Email = "123@123", Nom = "n1", Prenom = "p1", Statut = "s1", Telephone = "123" }, new PersonnelModel { id = 2, Email = "1234@1234", Nom = "n2", Prenom = "p2", Statut = "s2", Telephone = "1234" } };
            e.personnels = list;
            return View("EditPersonnelModel",e);
        }
```

EditViewModel:

```
public class EditViewModel
    {
        public List<PersonnelModel> personnels { get; set; }
    }
```

PersonnelModel:

```
public class PersonnelModel
    {
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Statut { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        
    }
```

View:

```
@model EditViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditPersonnelModel";
}

<h1>EditPersonnelModel</h1>

@foreach (var item in Model.personnels)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <form asp-action="EditPers" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.id">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.id" name="id">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.Nom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Nom" name="Nom">


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Prenom" name="Prenom">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Prenom" class="text-danger"></span>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Email" name="Email">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Telephone" name="Telephone">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@item.Statut" name="Statut">
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Statut" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-info text-white " />

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>}
```

Result:
[image]